# How to have two input text boxes in AppleScript

Tags: input, textbox, dialog, applescript

I would like to use 2 textboxes in one AppleScript dialog box.  I have seen multiple posts about how to use delimiters to seperate one boxes into two inputs with commas - **that is NOT what I want to do**.  I would like it to be like my attached screenshot.[image: Example of dialog box type]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pure AppleScript can't create a dialog box with two text fields.
Your screenshot shows a Cocoa dialog box.

However you can do it using AppleScriptObjC code

Comment: Is there some way to create a Cocoa scriptlet inside of an AppleScript?  And how similar is Cocoa to AppleScript?  Sorry I seem like a noob, I've just never used Cocoa

Comment: I dont believe that is possible but you can build Cocoa AppleScript (ASObjC) Apps with Xcode (free on the app store or downloadable on the apple developer site)

Answer (score 1):

AppleScript Alone can't have 2 text inputs UNLESS you use this command:

```
do shell script "" with administrator privileges
```

This will ask you for the system username and password BUT with no output, otherwise you have to use Cocoa AppleScript/AppleScriptObjC which you can connect the windows text fields to the AppleScript.

Here is how to do it with 1 text input:

```
display dialog "Window Text" default answer ""
```

(the "default answer" key gives the dialog box a text input and returns it)

Hope this helped!